# How to test a class that depends on an external collection in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

One of my classes, `Foo`, has a method, `Foo::bar()`, that relies on an injected collection, `BazCollection`, and values extracted from that collection's items.  I need to unit test `Foo::bar()`, and I can't figure out how to properly mock the `BazCollection` dependency such that it wouldn't break the internal implementation of `Foo::bar()`.

So, for example:

```
class Foo {
    public function bar(BazCollection $bazzes) {
        foreach ($bazzes as $baz) {
            // Do something with $baz->boz(), and modify $result
        }

        return $result;
    }
}

class BazCollection implements IteratorAggregate {
    protected $_bazzes;

    public function getIterator() {
        return new ArrayIterator($this->_bazzes);
    }
}

class Baz {
    public function boz() { /* ... */ }
}
```

How would I mock `BazCollection` properly in order to isolate and test the `Foo::bar()` logic?

I assume that creating an actual instance of `BazCollection` is a no-no, since then my test would depend on `BazCollection` working properly?

Comment: this link should point your way: http://www.davegardner.me.uk/blog/2011/03/04/mocking-iterator-with-phpunit/

Comment: Your question is a bit inclear (incomplete?). What causes you the problem to mock both BazCollection as the bazzes it contains? Further: Why does the bar() method operator on an iterator? E.g. why aren't you calling it inside a foreach instead, so you would only have the manipulation method on the baz / for the baz and not for the collection?